# Allow MySQL access from given IP range

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Normally, I use host "localhost".  But now I wish to allow MySQL Workbench to access.  Workbench is located on a Windows PC with IP 10.x.x.x, and MySql is located on 10.y.y.y.  I've tried the following to no avail.  How is this accomplished?

```
CREATE USER 'myUserName'@'10.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'myPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'myUserName'@'10.%';
```

This is what phpMyAdmin displays when exporting the users:

```
# Privileges for `myUserName`@`10%`

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUserName'@'10%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxx';


# Privileges for `myUserName`@`10.%`

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUserName'@'10.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxx';


# Privileges for `myUserName`@`localhost`

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myUserName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: How do you access the remote MySQL? You need to specify the IP address like this `mysql -u windowUser -p -h 10.y.y.y`

Comment: "to no avail" means what, specifically?  What's the exact error message?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  `Operation failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

Comment: That isn't a permissions issue.  This error is telling you two things: (1) you're trying to connect to the MySQL server running on the machine where you're sitting ("localhost") -- not what you intended -- and, (2) not surprisingly in this case, there's no running MySQL server there (at your own machine).  (Error 10061 is a network-level error that translates to `Connection refused` -- which is not an authentication error.)  You need to be telling Workbench the IP address of the server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot  Thank you, I've tested it and you are correct.  It also appears that I can use either `10%` or `10.%` to specify that only users logged on the 10 network can access.